# Actions in alertdialog are transparent when using banner as content for alert dialog in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-alertdialog, google-mobile-ads

When I use a banner inside an alert dialog, the action widget becomes transparent.
I am using google_mobile_ads plugin.

....

```
 final BannerAd _bannerAdForExitDialog = BannerAd(
    adUnitId: Constants.getBannerAdUnit,
    size: AdSize.mediumRectangle,
    request: const AdRequest(),
    listener: BannerAdListener(
      onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        ad.dispose();
      },
    ),
  );
```

.....

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _bannerAdForExitDialog.load();
  }
```

....

```
  TextStyle _getActionTextStyle() {
    return const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.red);
  }
```

....

```
 AlertDialog(
          title: const Text(
            "Do you want to exit?",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          content: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            height: _bannerAdForExitDialog.size.height.toDouble(),
            width: _bannerAdForExitDialog.size.width.toDouble(),
            child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAdForExitDialog),
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              //onPressed: () => exit(0),
              onPressed: () => print('yes'),
              child: Text(
                'Yes',
                style: _getActionTextStyle(),
              ),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text(
                'No',
                style: _getActionTextStyle(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
```

.....

Here is the output. Even if I have assigned a red color to 'yes' and 'no' text buttons the color is still transparent

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around

```
  Future<bool> _showExitPopup(context) async {
    return await showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text(
            "Do you want to exit?",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          content: Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  _getWidgetIfTrue(
                    condition: _isBannerAdForExitDialogLoaded,
                    widget: SizedBox(
                      height: _bannerAdForExitDialog.size.height.toDouble(),
                      width: _bannerAdForExitDialog.size.width.toDouble(),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: _bannerAdForExitDialog.size.width.toDouble(),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () => exit(0),
                          //onPressed: () => print('yes'),
                          child: Text(
                            'Yes',
                            style: Constants.getTextStyleForAlertDialogActions(
                              context,
                            ).copyWith(color: Colors.red),
                          ),
                        ),
                        TextButton(
                          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                          child: Text(
                            'No',
                            style: Constants.getTextStyleForAlertDialogActions(
                              context,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              _getWidgetIfTrue(
                condition: _isBannerAdForExitDialogLoaded,
                widget: _getBannerAd(_bannerAdForExitDialog),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```